# How can I make a parallel operation faster than the serial version?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm attempting to "map" a function onto an array. However when trying both simple and complex functions, the parallel version is always slower than the serial version. How can I improve the performance of a parallel computation in R?

**Simple parallel example:**

```
library(parallel)

# Number of elements
arrayLength = 100
# Create data
input = 1:arrayLength

# A simple computation
foo = function(x, y) x^y - x^(y-1)

# Add complexity
iterations = 5 * 1000 * 1000

# Perform complex computation on each element
compute = function (x) {
  y = x
  for (i in 1:iterations) {
    x = foo(x, y)
  }
  return(x)
}

# Parallelized compute
computeParallel = function(x) {
  # Create a cluster with 1 fewer cores than are available.
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) # 8-1 cores 
  # Send static vars & funcs to all cores
  clusterExport(cl, c('foo', 'iterations'))
  # Map
  out = parSapply(cl, x, compute)
  # Clean up
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(out)
}

system.time(out <- compute(input)) # 12 seconds using 25% of cpu
system.time(out <- computeParallel(input)) # 160 seconds using 100% of cpu
```

Comment: The initialization of clusters takes time. Have you tried to initialize out your function?

Comment: It's not a fair comparison, but I just tried it. No substantial change. I'd be surprised if initialization could explain the order of magnitude difference.

Comment: I don't use these parallel packages much, but literally every single time there's a question on SO about why parallelizing is slower than serial its because the overhead of splitting the task dominates the complexity of the task itself.

Comment: @joran: I've shifted the complexity from the number of elements (1M to 100) to the "within-core" loop (500 to 5M). Each thread performs 5 million iterations, and I'm still seeing similar results. Do you still think splitting is the dominating factor?

Comment: I ran your original code with 1M elements.  While my elapsed times are not exactly as yours, they are similar.  But more interesting are the system and user times.  Single-threaded: user 19.981 system 0.006 elapsed 20.028.  Parallel: user 0.166 system 0.164 elapsed 121.543.  Note the very low "user" and "system" results.  I suspect that there is a lock on the result vector, and too much time is spent resolving locks.  If you're running on an Intel CPU, I would recommend downloading an evaluation version of VTune to analyze the system while running this code.

Comment: I'm getting similarly results for the 100 x 5M version: (<0.1 seconds) user and system times with ~150 second elapsed time. If the problem is caused by locks on the output variable, what can be done to resolve it?

Comment: You're putting the solution ahead of the problem.  If a profiler determines that the time is being taken in a lock attempt, it will also show where the lock is being taken.  A vector of length 1M should not need a global lock, but perhaps it has one.  That would explain the extreme time taken by the code that you present, and the fix would be fixing the code in the package parallel.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: I used up my vtune evaluation a while ago on something unrelated, and I'm having trouble finding an OSS alternative. (AMD's won't work on intel chips)

Comment: @sharoz I am sorry to hear that.  I have some paid licenses through work, so I'll try to get some time to analyze this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you traded off *all* of the vectorization for parallelization, and that's a bad trade. You need to keep as much vectorization as possible to have any hope of getting an improvement with parallelization for this kind of problem.

The pvec function in the parallel package can be a good solution to this kind of problem, but it isn't supported in parallel on Windows. A more general solution which works on Windows is to use foreach with the itertools package which contains functions which are useful for iterating over various objects. Here's an example that uses the "isplitVector" function to create one subvector for each worker:

```
library(doParallel)
library(itertools)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
registerDoParallel(cl)
computeChunk <- function(x) {
  foreach(xc=isplitVector(x, chunks=getDoParWorkers()),
          .export=c('foo', 'iterations', 'compute'), 
          .combine='c') %dopar% {
    compute(xc)
  }
}
```

This still may not compare very well to the pure vector version, but it should get better as the value of "iterations" increases. It may actually help to decrease the number of workers unless the value of "iterations" is very large.

Comment: I guess I assumed that the chunking was done automatically by `parSapply`. This dropped the time below the serial time.

Answer (score 0):

`parSapply` will run the function on each element of `input` separately, which means you are giving up the speed you gained from writing `foo` and `compute` in a vectorized fashion.

`pvec` will run a vectorized function on multiple cores by chunks. Try this:

```
system.time(out <- pvec(input, compute, mc.cores=4))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I that function isn't supported on Windows for mc.cores>1